# DNS configuration issues. Clients inside network unable to resolve DNS server's name

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, ubuntu-12.04

Setup the DNS service on Ubuntu 12.04 64 and all apears to be well except that my dhcp clients do not recognize my DNS servers hostname.

When doing a `nslookup` on one of my Windows clients, I get

```
C:\Users\chad>nslookup
Default Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.1.2
```

Where I would expect the FQDN in the spot where UnKnown is seen.  The DNS server know's itself pretty well, but I think only because I have an entry in the `/etc/hosts` file to resolve.  There's so many places to look I don't even know where to begin.  Are there any logs I can look at? Something.

Places I've looked at and configured:

```
/etc/bind/zones/domain.com.db
/etc/bind/zones/rev.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa
/etc/bind/named.conf.local
```

**EDIT:**

'/etc/bind/zones/rev.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa'

```
@ IN SOA dns-serv1.mydomain.com admin@mydomain.com. (
2006081401;
28800;
604800;
604800;
86400
)

IN NS dns-serv1.mydomain.com.
2 IN PTR dns-serv1
2 IN PTR mydomain.com
```

**EDIT 2:**

'/etc/bind/named.conf.local'

```
zone "mydomain.com" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/mydomain.com.db";
};

zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/rev.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa";
};
```

Comment: What's the reverse lookup zone's configuration look like?

Comment: @ShaneMadden Edit Updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a PTR record on your reverse zone definition (rev.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa), something like

```
2     PTR     dns.domain.com
```

Also to do a forward lookup you need to configure a NS record on your forward zone definition (domain.com.db)

```
dns   NS      192.168.1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Entries in zone files are considered relative without a trailing dot, so this...

```
2 IN PTR dns-serv1
2 IN PTR mydomain.com
```

...really means...

```
2 IN PTR dns-serv1.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.
2 IN PTR mydomain.com.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.
```

...which doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

What you probably want is:

```
2 IN PTR dns-serv1.mydomain.com.
```

I'm a little surprised that Windows isn't showing you the contents of the `PTR` record anyway, though.  What's the `zone` block for the reverse zone look like in `named.conf.local`?